# The charge density of the electron cloud of a hydrogen atom has a total charge different than an electron's charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, charge

The charge density of the electron cloud for a hydrogen atom in the ground state is according to quantum mechanics:$$\rho(r)=\dfrac{q}{\pi a^3}e^{-2r/a}\tag{1}$$ where $a=a_0$ is Bohr's radius and $q$ is the charge of an electron.

After solving an exercise, I noticed something weird about that distribution: the formula for the charge $Q(r)$ of a sphere of radius $r<a$ when we apply Gauss' Theorem to find the electric field created by the electron cloud is $$Q(r)=q\left(1-e^{-2r/a}\left(1+2\frac{r}{a}+2\frac{r^2}{a^2}\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

Letting $r=a$ in formula $(2)$ (not the racing car) I expected the natural result $Q(a)=q\approx-1.602.10^{-19}\,\rm C$, but in reality we get: $$Q(a)=(1-5e^{-2})q\approx-5.18.10^{-20}\,\rm C$$

Formula $(2)$ doesn't seem to be wrong for me. I thought that it's ok to get a different result since it can be close though, but in reality the relative error is $$\left|\dfrac{q-Q(a)}{q}\right|=5e^{-2}\approx 67.66\,\%$$ which is really big.

So, would you please tell me why is the charge distribution in $(1)$ accepted when it represents a charge much less than an electron's charge?

Comment: The charge of $(1)$ is obviously not completely inside the Bohr radius. It has to give the charge of the electron when *integrated over all of space*. The quantum mechanical result has *no reason* to give you the electron's charge confined inside the (pseudo-classical) Bohr radius, why do you think there's any other explanation than "Don't use the Bohr radius!"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind You're right! When $r\to +\infty$ we get $q$. I'm having my first course in Quantum Mechanics this semester so we're still in elementary parts. There's still one thing  that bothers me: formula $(1)$ is given in the ground state. The electron can't be too far away. Could you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, the electron isn't far away indeed. If you integrate charge density over $r\in[0,4a_0]$ you'll get almost $0.99q$.

Comment: @Scientifica The electron **can** be found far away, even a million meters away. It just doesn't happen very often because the amplitude for a proton-electron separation of a million meters is nonzero but quite small.